# Trouble with log4j configuration

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have been trying to change the logging from console to both console as well as file. Looking at the large documentation on log4j I was able to add the appender as shown in the code below. However I don't seem to be getting logs in the specified file.

Any ideas what might be wrong? Here is my log4j.xml (already located at src/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
        <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="file" value="/data/MFlogs/log.log"/>
        <param name="immediateFlush" value="true"/>
        <param name="threshold" value="debug"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>


    <root>
        <priority value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

change  file path tag. try it with double slash.
value="//data//MFlogs//log.log"

Comment: Why you are using xml file, you can do the same thing with properties file. in xml if there is a whitespace, it create problem. try to copy the content then delete it from xml , save the blank file again paste it and save.

Comment: everything looks fine in your xml, sometime eclipse/IDE didn't parse xml file, try to restart eclipse/IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding full path to path location or add `${catalina.home}/logs/myApp.log` to it.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975289/log4j-relative-file-path) question, it tells how to use relative path. It is easy if you use [properties](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/) file instead of [xml](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-xml-example/) file.

Comment: Okay I'm confused. Are you asking me to use absolute or relative? What I am using is the absolute path. 
`value="/data/MFlogs/log.log"/>`
I'll try with relative.

Comment: If it is absolute path, check permissions of the location or some other issue.

Comment: All three have the correct owner. This is really puzzling.