# How can I get the "logs" path for a web service application?

Tags: java

I am new to the Java language.  I've written a Java web service application using the NetBeans IDE and it's working fine.

I want to maintain logs in a separate text file for each user login in the logs folder of the web service application, but I haven't figured out how to get the root folder path of the web service application.

I am .NET programmer, so in .NET I can use `Server.MapPath("~/logs")` to get the logs folder path which is present under the web service application root folder.  How can I do the equivalent using Java?

Comment: You should have a look at [Log4j 2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/). It is a great lib for logging, and when using it, you will be the one defining where is the log output done

Answer (score 0):

The following links might help. google it before you raise your question.

[log4j relative file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975289/log4j-relative-file-path)

[set an absolute path for a "log4j.properties" file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27123578/set-an-absolute-path-for-a-log4j-properties-file)

[What is log4j's default log file dumping path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335984/what-is-log4js-default-log-file-dumping-path)